# Added element prevents code from adding new rows to table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api

I have some problems adding rows to a table in a div tag, because of another tag in it.

I know that it would be nice if I can change the id of the table, but because it is generated, I am not able to change them. I can only change id of the div encasing the table.

```
<!--Adding does not work on this table -->
<h3>Wednesday</h3>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult('wed')">Insert new row</button>
<div id="wed">
<strong>Even this stops it from adding</strong> <!--This is the problem -->
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>   

<!--Adding works on this table -->
<h3>Thursday</h3>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult('thu')">Insert new row</button>
<div id="thu">
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>   

function displayResult(number) {
    var elemList=document.getElementById(number).childNodes;
    var table=elemList[1];
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML="New";
    cell2.innerHTML="New";
}
```

[Here is jsFiddle illustrating the problem I have](http://bit.ly/13SYyPc)

Comment: What's behind the obfuscated shortener? Please flesh out your question.

Comment: It would be nice to see some in here, but the fiddle in the link is clear enough with what's wrong.

Comment: @krillgar, [we like a question to contain all the content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) so that if, for instance, the link goes bad, the question and its answers are still useful for future visitors.

Comment: Point taken, though that still doesn't warrant down votes. Though, your comment was better and more constructive than gdoron's.

Comment: I made changes.. Can someone unban me too? :(

Comment: The problem is caused by how `.childNodes` works.  Adding an new element, changes the number of `childNodes`.  `childNodes` returns a collection of nodes that can be referenced by index.  To see how many children are in the collection, you can use `alert(elemList.length);`  In the jsFiddle, changing the index from 1 to 3, makes the second button work:  `var table=elemList[3];`   You could try `getElementsByTagName("table")`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume the getting of elements by index is what the problem is (without seeing the code that generates the table, it's hard to say for sure), and suggest that once you have the div, you `getElementsByTagName('table')[0]` and see if you can't work from there.

I'd also suggest that most of what you're doing is a lot easier w/ jquery, if you have the ability to add that to the project, I'd recommend it.